# specific value based filtering on a large dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having a very large dictionary. Here is a small sampling of my dictionary:

```
dictionary = {'1': {'a':'aa','b':'bb','c':'cc','d':'dd'}, 
              '2': {'a':'aa','b':'bb','c':'cc','d':'dd'}, 
              '3': {'a':'aa','b':'bb','c':'cc','d':'dd'} }
```

I just want to filter out the a & c.

**Desired output:**

```
dictionary = { '1': {'a':'aa','c':'cc'}, 
               '2': {'a':'aa','c':'cc'}, 
               '3': {'a':'aa','c':'cc'} }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What isn't working? Where are you having trouble?

Comment: Do you literally have a dictionary indexed by stringified integers? Have you considered using a list instead? Do all of the inner dictionaries have the same keys?

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary comprehensions to the rescue:

```
{k: {'a': v['a'], 'c': v['c']} for k, v in dictionary.iteritems()}
```

This assumes that all dictionaries in have those keys set and that you are using Python 2.7.

A more generic version:

```
def filtered_dicts(d, keys):
    return {k: {vk: v[vk] for vk in v.viewkeys() & keys} for k, v in d.iteritems()}

dictionary = filtered_dicts(dictionary, {'a', 'c'})
```

This will work even if the keys are not present in all values of `dictionary`.

Any iterable will do for `keys` here; I used a `set` literal here but a list or tuple or even a string would work too.

A Python 3 version of the latter:

```
def filtered_dicts(d, keys):
    return {k: {vk: v[vk] for vk in v.keys() & keys} for k, v in d.items()}
```

Quick demo using Python 3:

```
>>> dictionary = {'1': {'a':'aa','b':'bb','c':'cc','d':'dd'}, '2': {'a':'aa','b':'bb','c':'cc','d':'dd'}, '3':{'a':'aa','b':'bb','c':'cc','d':'dd'}}
>>> def filtered_dicts(d, keys):
...     return {k: {vk: v[vk] for vk in v.keys() & keys} for k, v in d.items()}
... 
>>> filtered_dicts(dictionary, {'a', 'c'})
{'3': {'c': 'cc', 'a': 'aa'}, '2': {'c': 'cc', 'a': 'aa'}, '1': {'c': 'cc', 'a': 'aa'}}
```